# Is there a way in Python I can display only unattached volumes (disks) in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have the region/zone/project ID
I am using compute_v1.AggregatedListInstancesRequest()

I would like to display only unattached volumes (disks) using Python and GCP API of the relevant region

I expect to see volumes unattached to any instance (orphan) in the relevant region/project in GCP

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries. If the answer was helpful, What should I do [when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

This [**official python library reference**](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.types.Disk) about disks, explains in detail about the attributes that are available for fetching data related to a disk in GCP. Among these attributes **last_attach_timestamp** and **last_detach_timestamp** will come in handy for your use case, compare both these timestamps and check which is the latest one. If the **last_attach_timestamp is latest** that means the disk **is in use** and if the **last_detach_timestamp is latest** the disk **is not being used**. In parallel you can use **zone** attribute to fetch details for a particular zone.

There is a [**lab**](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/7797?parent=catalog) on how to delete unused resources using python code in Cloud Functions along with Cloud Scheduler and you can have a glance at it.